# Ansible gets stuck after changing hostname

Tags: ansible

I found that the ansible will be stuck when I change a host's HOSTNAME.

```
- name: Set hostname
  hostname: NEW_HOSTNAME
- name: Copy file
  copy: src=source_file dest=dest_file owner=root mode=0644
```

The task of `Copy file` will be stuck forever. And it is also stuck for any other different ansible command.

Is there anyone know this issue? I cannot found precise information from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your playbook with -vvvv to display debugging information? It would be good to post a copy of that up for more information. Sorry, I'd toss this in as a comment, but can't do that until 50 rep.

Comment: Though you do not have reuptation to comments on question, it is not a good way to represent. Better wait until you have proper reputation to comment

Comment: Actually, asking for output this way is the only method I have for requesting further information. Ansible is an area I have extensive knowledge in and once I get an answer together, I can edit the answer. If I cannot provide an answer, I can delete this one.